# Is $f(n)=O(g(n))$ or $f(n)=\Omega(g(n))$ when $f(n) = (\log n)^{\log n}$ and $g(n) = n/\log n$?

Tags: asymptotics

I have showed that $f(n)=\Omega(g(n))$ in the following way.

> We assume that $${\log n}^{\log n} \leq n/\log n$$ 
>                        $$\implies \log n \times \log \log n \leq \log n - \log \log n$$ 
>                        $$\implies \log \log n \times ( \log n -1 ) \leq \log n     $$ which is a contradiction when $n \geq 1$.
>   Thus we conclude $f(n) = \Omega(g(n))$ where we consider $c=1$ and $n_0 = 1$.

I will be thankful if anyone can comment that if my approach is correct or if incorrect may please provide the solution approach.

Comment: $O$, $\Omega$, and the like regard the behaviors of the functions as $n \rightarrow \infty$. So to prove that $f \in \Omega(g)$ you should show that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} cf - g \ge 0$ for some $c$. In this case you have $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} f-g = \infty$ by roughly the argument you made.

Comment: Thank you. So any help please on showing the limit is greater than 0. Seems to be quite complicated.

Or would you propose any other easier way to solve it?

Comment: Also $$(\log n)^{\log n} = (e^{\log\log n})^{\log n} = e^{\log n \cdot \log\log n} = (e^{\log n})^{\log\log n} = n^{\log\log n}.$$

Comment: You basically did it. Using your method, show that $(\log n)^{\log n} - \frac{n}{\log n} = (\log\log n)(\log n) - \log n - \log\log n$. Then state that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}$ of this expression is $\infty$. Then you are done.

Comment: @ Solomonoff's Secret I think it will be equivalent to instead of equal to. Is not it?